# Installing Python modules for OpenERP 6.1 in Windows

Tags: python, odoo

I installed OpenERP 6.1 on windows using the AllInOne package. I did NOT install Python separately. Apparently OpenERP folders already contain the required python executables.

Now when I try to install certain addons, I usually come across requirements to install certain python modules. E.g. to install Jasper_Server, I need to install http2, pypdf and python-dime.

As there is no separate Python installation, there is no C:\Python or anything like that. Where and how do I install these python packages so that I am able to install the addon?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Please check this link, may be helpful for you.
http://www.zbeanztech.com/blog/openerp-source-eclipse-under-windows

if you install the python package separately, then you have to add the bin path of the installed package to the system environment variable.

Comment: That link is to build openerp code on windows. All I am trying to do is to install an addon which requires some python packages. I'm hoping there is a simpler and shorter way. E.g. is there a path variable somewhere that would make openerp use that installation of python instead of its default? So then we can install python separately and install python packages in it.

Comment: Thanks. This forced me to eventually setup the openerp dev environment.

Answer (score 1):

Good question..

Openerp on windows uses a dll for python (python26.dll in /Server/server of the openerp folder in program files). It looks like all the extra libraries are in the same folder, so you should be able to download the extra libraries to that folder and restart the service. (I usually stop the service and run it manually from the command line - its easier to see if there are any errors etc while debugging)

Let us know if you get it working!

Comment: Thanks, I ended up setting up the entire openerp-python development environment in eclipse, thanks to PRK for his tutorial. But someone (maybe myself) should try the solution you proposed as well.